# Connect to an already running instance of Chrome from Puppetry

Tags: automated-tests

There are some test cases when we need to connect Puppetry to an already ruining instance of chrome. For example you cannot solve reCaptcha with automated tests, but you can do it manually and run the tests on the affected Chrome instance.

So how can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect we need to start Chrome in command-line with remote-debugging-port parameter.

Window:

```
start chrome.exe –remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=remote-profile
```

macOS

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --user-data-dir=$(mktemp -d -t 'chrome-remote_data_dir')
```

Linux

```
google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Next we navigate in the started browser to http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/version. On the page we can see a JSON object.

[image]

We need to copy the value of webSocketDebuggerUrl property. 
In Puppetry we open "Run Tests" modal window (F6), switch to "Browser options" tab and paste the saved value into "WS Endpoint" input.

[image]

Now we can press "Run".